# Assigning value according to interval in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to assign value (probability) if the values from `Random.length` fall into given interval based on data.frame `Data$Measure`.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(Measure=sort(rnorm(10,5,2),decreasing=FALSE),
        Probability=sort(runif(10,0,1),decreasing=FALSE))
Random.length <- as.vector(sort(rnorm(5,5,2),decreasing=FALSE))
```

Here I would like to be able to assign probability to the `Random.length` vector corresponding the value `Measure` from data.frame `Data`.

This is what I have tried. It kind of works. (only as good as to show what I mean ....)

```
AssignValue <- function (x,y,z){
CopyNumber <- rep(0, length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(x[i] <= y[1]) { CopyNumber[i] <- z[1]
} else if(x[i] > y[1] & x[i] < y[2]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[2]
} else if(x[i] > y[2] & x[i] < y[3]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[3]
} else if(x[i] > y[3] & x[i] < y[4]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[4]
} else if(x[i] > y[4] & x[i] < y[5]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[5]
} else if(x[i] > y[5] & x[i] < y[6]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[6]
} else if(x[i] > y[6] & x[i] < y[7]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[7]
} else if(x[i] > y[7] & x[i] < y[8]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[8]
} else if(x[i] > y[8] & x[i] < y[9]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[9]
} else if(x[i] > y[9]) {  CopyNumber[i] <- z[10]
}
}
CopyNumber
}


AssignValue(Random.length,Data$Measure,Data$Prob)
```

Now my data.frame `Data` is of length 51 so the actual loop I have is up to ...z[51] basically scanning through the whole data.frame. I just shortened this for demonstration. So the actual solution should be able to cope with possibly arbitrary length.

Also the solution should be able to work with arbitrary length of the `Random.length` vector.

EDIT: small mistake on the end of the loop, now corrected.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `cut` function.

Comment: I'm aware of function 'cut' but would not think its appropriate here...

Comment: You are definitely looking for cut.

Comment: yes, 'cut' will be part of it, I see it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure without your desired output posted, but this should work:

```
> Data$Prob[cut(Random.length, c(0, Data$Measure[1:9], Inf))]

[1] 0.1471136 0.5941420 0.8895393 0.8895393 0.9942698
```

To adjust the indices of `Data$Measure` programatically, you'll want `ind = 1:(nrow(Data)-1)`. I'd prefer to do that as a separate step to avoid clutter, but that's just me.

*from comments* `c(0, head(Data$Measure, -1), Inf)` is a simpler alternative

Comment: And to make that general w.r.t. vector length, just replace `Data$Measure[1:9]` with `head(Data$Measure, -1)`.

Comment: I would suggest using `findInterval` instead of `cut` in this case.  They will do essentially the same thing, but I think that `findInterval` is a little clearer.

Comment: In case of 'cut' I experienced now error (....breaks not unique), so it looks like it is because the vector contains zero.

Comment: That's because the vector that makes up your second argument has repeated values. Run `c(0, head(Data$Measure, -1), Inf)` to see where the repeated value is.